# KIE Drool Workbench: Unable to get to workbench UI due to "Forbidden" screen

Tags: jboss, wildfly, drools, drools-guvnor, kie-workbench

I have been trying follow the links and details available to set up a KIE Drools workbench for Drools like https://www.intertech.com/simple-setup-of-drools-kie-workbench-and-kie-server-in-one-wildfly-instance/.
From what I could analyze and read up KIE Drools Workbench will let me configure a rule engine through a front end and that Guvnor used to handle this aspect prior to workbench. These configured rules can be blended into my Spring Boot application to drive my loan application requirement. I hope that this understanding of usage of KIE Drools workbench is correct. Please confirm.

Below are the things I tried.

1. Set up KIE Workbench in Wildfly
2. Set up KIE Server in Wildfly

[image]

Getting them deployed I had to go through many issues which I was able to resolve like updating the jboss-deployment-structure.xml and executing using standalone-full.xml.

This is the UI I see now.

[image]

But for the workbench I am only seeing FORBIDDEN on screen.

[image]

Can you please suggest what can be done so that I can have the UI to create my custom rules.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought of updating that I was able to resolve the issue I faced. The only thing to be done is to follow the link I shared word by word :) . The users were created as stated and the exact version of war files were used and I am now able to access the workbench. Now on I will be exploring the usage.

[image]